# Zend Framework 3 Xampp database connection

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am new to Zend Framework 3 and I am doing [this](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/) tutorial:

I have a xampp, mysql setup.

I have done everything exactly like in this tutorial.  Now I am at the point where you configure the database connection. Further I have set up the controller and view.

In the tutorial link above , they are using php to create a database and then in config/autoload/global.php.....the following code:

```
return [
'db' => [
    'driver' => 'Pdo',
    'dsn'    => sprintf('sqlite:%s/data/zftutorial.db', realpath(getcwd())),
   ],
];
```

I  have edited this to:

```
'db' => [
'driver' => 'Pdo_Mysql',
'dsn'    => 'mysql:dbname=dbname;host=localhost;charset=utf8;username=myuser;password=mypassword',
],
```

When I call the url for the index view, there the following error:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\module\Album\src\Controller\AlbumController.php on line 15
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zendtest\module\Album\src\Controller\AlbumController.php
>   on line 22

The AlbumController:

```
 <?php

    namespace Album\Controller;

    use Album\Model\AlbumTable;
    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
    use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

    class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController {

    private $table;

    public function __construct(AlbumTable $table)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
    }


    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel([
            'albums' => $this->table->fetchAll(),
        ]);
    }

    }
```

I think that the connection doesn't work??

Answer (score 0):

can you share your "AlbumControllerFactory.php" ?

if you have not yet created the factory you should do.

1 - Create AlbumControllerFactory that implements FactoryInterface

2 - Inside __invoke function use the Container to inject AlbumTable to your controller

3 - config your mapping in module.config.php

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\AlbumController::class => Controller\Factory\AlbumControllerFactory::class,
```

Answer (score 0):

All simple, you have mistake in key `$this`, you did write `$htis` instead )